# necesito alguien me colabore con esta consulta

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla detalles_mensajeria1 la cual tiene dos registros, y necesito colaboración para esta consulta en mysql, ya que me arroja los dos registros y debería arrojar solo uno... el `OR` ya lo he reemplazado por el `AND` y nada

```
SELECT * 
FROM detalles_mensajeria1 
where mensajero_detalle LIKE 'Luis Muriel' 
    or mensajero_detalle LIKE 'Sebastian Hernandez' 
    and date(fecha_registro) BETWEEN '2018-07-12' and '2018-07-12'
    order by id_detalle


d_detalle id_usu fecha_registro fecha_entrega mensajero_detalle empleado contacto dir_contacto tel_contacto ubicación observación 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1 3 9/07/2018 10:28 12/07/2018 8:00 Luis Muriel Yuliana Ruiz SOS EPS Barrio Versalles 454545 Norte Prueba 
2 3 12/07/2018 10:31 12/07/2018 10:00 Sebastian Hernandez John Ramirez Confamdi Autopista Sur 6841000 Sur
```

Comment: Sería interesante conocer los datos de la tabla y sobre todo que es lo que deseas obtener. Viendo por encima diria que te faltan parentesis, si mal no recuerdo los `AND` tienen siempre preferencia sobre los `OR` por lo que te va a traer los registros entre las fechas indicadas y su valor sea 'Sebastian Hernandez' o los registros cuyo valor sea 'Luis Muriel' sin importar las fechas. Adicionalmente, el uso de `LIKE` sin `%` no tiene mucho sentido e incluso puede hacer tardar mas a la consulta.

Comment: hola, gracias por la respuesta, el caso es que la tabla tiene dos registros uno con luis con fecha del 09-07-2018 y otro con sebastian con fecha 12-07-2018 la consulta funciona pero me muestra los dos registros cuando debería mostrar solo el de sebastian del 12, hice lo que me dices pero el resultado es el mismo muestra los dos registros, no pude pegar la imagen de la estructura y datos de la tabla

Comment: Necesitariamos ver los datos... la consulta asi como esta es correcta, esto es un problema de datos (o de logica de la consulta)

Comment: id_detalle  id_usu  fecha_registro   fecha_entrega       mensajero_detalle        empleado           contacto       dir_contacto  tel_contacto   ubicación   observación
1                 3       9/07/2018 10:28  12/07/2018 8:00      Luis Muriel         Yuliana Ruiz      SOS EPS      Barrio Versalles   454545  Norte     Prueba 
   2                 3      12/07/2018 10:31  12/07/2018 10:00   Sebastian Hernandez    John Ramirez    Confamdi Autopista Sur   6841000  Sur      prueba
ojala me entiendas, para las fechas uso datetime

Comment: Siempre es bueno poner palabras a lo que hace la consulta, de ese modo podemos entendernos. Algo como: *tengo una tabla X que guarda tales datos y necesito mostrar X filas de los registros en los que el usuario sea X o el usuario sea Y y que al mismo tiempo la fecha sea Z*. Es un detalle mínimo que toda pregunta debería tener y que a la tuya le falta. A veces no sabemos resolver el problema porque ni siquiera lo hemos descrito. Por experiencia, describiendo un problema lo entiendes mejor y a veces hasta das con la solución haciendo eso.

Comment: hola, mi tabla guarda registros de mensajería, la consulta compara dos fechas en este caso iguales y a su vez los mensajeros que estén en el rango de las fechas seleccionadas, el problema es que me arroja todos los registros cuando en la consulta se especifica una fecha igual osea del 12-07-2018 que seria el mensajero Sebastian no debe salir el otro mensajero Luis que es del 09-07-2018, aclaro que en un momento dado pueden ser fechas diferentes cuando tenga mas registros, ese es el problema ojala m entiendan.

Comment: Ahora se te entiende mejor, aunque lo de tu anterior comentario debería ser el principio de tu pregunta y no constar en un simple comentario. Todavía hay algo que no queda y sea lo que quizá explique el uso de `BETWEEN` en la consulta. ¿Cuando dices que las fechas podrían ser diferentes a qué te refieres? Y en ese caso, ¿cuáles son los resultados esperados? Supongamos que buscas por un rango de fechas y el mismo usuario tiene varios mensajes en ese rango de fecha... te va a arrojar varias filas. ¿Es el resultado deseado? Es necesario que aclares esa parte, poniéndolo en el cuerpo de la preg.

Comment: ok..¿Cuando dices que las fechas podrían ser diferentes a qué te refieres? esto quiere decir que en la consulta se compara el mismo dia 2018-07-12 pero puede ser también por ejemplo  entre (between) 2018-07-12 y 2018-07-20.. y ¿cuáles son los resultados esperados? en mi caso me debe arrojar un registro del mensajero Sebastian que es del 2018-07-12 y claro si tengo un mensajero con varios registros en la misma fecha si me los debe mostrar todos ese es el resultado deseado, no me debe salir el registro de fecha 2018-07-09

Comment: hola @A.Cedano, ya fue solucionado por Carmen, gracias por tu ayuda y tendré en cuenta tus recomendaciones.

Comment: Bien, me alegro de que la respuesta de @Carmen te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes una unica fecha no es necesario usar between, y el campo de detalle al poder tener mas de un valor lo recoges con or pero usando parentesis para separarlo del campo fecha.

Si traes un unico registro como resultado el order tampoco es necesario porque ralentiza la query. Y en los nombres no es necesario like si vas a poner el valor exacto del campo.

```
SELECT * FROM detalles_mensajeria1 
WHERE fecha_registro BETWEEN '2018-07-12' AND '2018-07-12'
      AND (mensajero_detalle = 'Luis Muriel' 
      OR mensajero_detalle = 'Sebastian Hernandez')
```

Comment: hola @carmen gracias por la respuesta, la cuestión es que yo comparo con dos fechas datetime para que sea un rango determinado y lo que quiero es que traiga los registros de un mensajero determinado o de los dos si ambos concuerdan con la fecha, en esta caso no concuerdan por que tienen fechas diferentes, espero me explique, si me pueden decir como pego los datos y la estructura de la tabla les agradecería para que me entiendan mejor.

Comment: @somyfras entonces si usa el between, lo he editado. Las tablas las puedes copiar como html y pegarlas o sino con una imagen

Comment: hola @carmen si me funcionó, estaba mal escrito el nombre es Hernandez por eso no mostraba, muchisimas gracias...

Comment: Estupendo. Un placer :)